# Quarkus - Start web server on demand

Tags: java, rest, kotlin, quarkus

There is a CLI application written in Quarkus, it works as follows:

```
$ quarkus-app --input Hello
Output: olleH
```

Now there should also be the possibility to call this via a REST. However, this server should only be stared if the argument "--server" is passed:

```
$ quarkus-app --server &
Listening on '127.0.0.1:7070'
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:7070/api/reverse?input=Hello
Output: olleH
```

Now how do I get the WebServer to start only on "--server"?

My code currently looks like this:

```kotlin
@QuarkusMain
class CommandLine : QuarkusApplication {

    override fun run(vararg args: String?): Int {
        val options: Options = Options()
        options.addOption("i", "input", false, "Input to reverse")
        options.addOption("s", "server", false, "Start server")

        val parser: CommandLineParser = DefaultParser()
        val cmd: CommandLine = parser.parse(options, args)
        if (cmd.hasOption("server")) {
          // TODO: Start server
        } else if (cmd.hasOption("input")) {
          println("Output: ${cmd.getOptionValue("input").toString().reversed()}")
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: What stack is your "server" written in?

Comment: The server does not exist yet. Simply a normal Quarkus endpoint should be made available: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json

So its part of the application!

Comment: Okay understood. What you are describing cannot be done

Comment: This is now possible via `Quarkus.run()`. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77982732/4275911

Comment: Start a webserver with Vertx when the “—server” is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by defining a `QuarkusMain` and later calling `Quarkus.run()`.

```kotlin
import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain

@QuarkusMain
object Main {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        if (args.isNotEmpty() && args[0] == "--serve") {
            // Start HTTP server
            Quarkus.run(*args)
        } else if (args.size >= 2 && args[0] == "--input") {
            // Run CLI logic without starting HTTP server
            runCliLogic(args[1])
        } else {
            println("Usage: application [--serve | --input]")
        }
    }

    private fun runCliLogic(content: String) {
        // Implement your CLI logic here
        println(content.reversed())
    }
}
```

In addition, `io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy` must of course be installed and a resource must be defined:

```kotlin
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@Path("api/reverse")
class ReverseResource {

    @GET
    fun reverseInput(@QueryParam("input") input: String?): Response {
        if (input.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("Input parameter is required")
                .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .build()
        }

        val reversedInput = input.reversed()
        return Response.ok(reversedInput).build()
    }
}
```

Comment: This endpoint will also be accessible even when you don’t provide “—server”.

Comment: @Serkan for me it does work. The endpoint is only available with "--serve", without you can not access any endpoint.